# Mysql/PHP password verify not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched all over to find a answer to my question, but I can't find it.

I'm trying to make a login system with PHP and a MySQL database and I'm having a problem with the verify function.

To hash passwords I use this code:

```
$hash = password_hash('$passwordPost', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

The hashed password gets stored in my database as a whole (the database field is a `VARCHAR(255)`).

For verifying passwords I use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Gebruikers WHERE Email = '$emailPost'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if(password_verify($passwordPost, $row["Paswoord"])) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $row["Email"];
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $row["Rol"];
        echo("Logged in als: " + $_SESSION['login_user'] + " met als rol: " + $_SESSION['rol']);
      break;
    }else {
        echo("Your Login Name or Password is invalid");
        break;
    }
}
```

I've also checked if the hash created is the same as the hash getting fetched and that seems to be the case.

The function password_verify does however seem to be working when using test values (not from database).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you stored a literal string and it failed *silently*.

Comment: `echo("Logged in als: " + $_SESSION['login_user'] + " met als rol: " + $_SESSION['rol']);` - this isn't math. You may have come from a JS/C background. PHP uses dots, not plus signs to concatenate.

Comment: Ow yes indeed i knew that! Just been a while. Thanks!
But that would not be the cause of my problem unfortunatly

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are parsed literally, so when `$foo = "bar"`, `'$foo'` = "$foo" while `"$foo"` = "bar"
Above all, the quotes are unnecessary, you can simply use `$foo`.
So in your case, that would look like:

```
$hash = password_hash($passwordPost, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

With that, your [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) are incorrect, where the correct usage would be `$a = $b.$c`, not `$a = $b + $c`.

You might also want to note that in the example provided, there is a typo here: `if(password_verify($passwordPost, $row["Paswoord"])) {`, where it says "Passwoord" instead of "Password."

Hope I helped! -CM

Comment: you missed something and more information as to what they need to do in order to rectify this

Comment: wondering why you overwrote my edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47372672/3

Comment: What a stupid mistake.
Anyway thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Whoops, @Fred-ii-! That must've accidentally happened while I was writing the typo bit, feel free to re-add it.

Comment: No problem, @JariFlederick. If this is the correct answer to the question and you are currently able, please mark it as an answer so the community can look here for the solution.

Comment: Just did. Had to wait a some time.